# Postgres table contains 1 column, and that column is PK. How to insert new record?

Tags: database-design, primary-key, postgresql-9.3

In my application, I have an abstract base class, and 2 derived classes.  The number of derived classed will probably not increase.  If it does, it won't be more than a few.

The class structure looks like this:

```
abstract class Base
{
    int FirstParameter
    int SecondParameter
    abstract void DoSomeWork();
}

class Foo : Base
{
    int FoosParameter
    override void DoSomeWork(){...}
}

class Bar : Base
{
    override void DomeWork(){...}
}
```

Essentially, `Bar` only needs the data provided by `Base`, but does its own work on the data.  From a data standpoint, `Bar` and `Base` are the same.  `Foo`, on the other hand, has some extra data tacked on to it.

The database has 3 tables, one for `Base`, one for `Foo`, and for `Bar`.  Since the number of subclasses is not going to grow significantly, it makes more sense to give each class its own table.

**tblBase**:

```
base_id PK,
first_parameter int not null,
second_parameter int not null,
foo_id int,
bar_id int
```

**tblFoo**:

```
foo_id PK,
foos_parameter int not null,
```

**tblBar**:

```
bar_id PK
```

`tblBar` consists of 1 column, which is the auto incrementing primary key.  The primary key is stored in `tblBase` in column `bar_id`, which will identify any `Base` as being a `Bar`.

Now, for the real kicker:  How does one insert a new record into `tblBar`, when the only column is the auto incrementing primary key?  I suppose I could do

```
insert into tblBar(bar_id) 
select max(bar_id) + 1 
from tblBar
```

but that seems a bit....clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a `insert .. select max() ...` is a bad idea to begin with as it doesn't work correctly in a multi user environment. Plus it would get the sequence behind the `serial` column out of sync with the already generated values.

What you are looking for is:

```
insert into bar (bar_id) values (default);
```

Another option would be explicitly call `nextval()` when inserting.

```
insert into bar (bar_id) values (nextval('bar_bar_id_seq'));
```

Comment: That did it for me.  I also discovered that you can do the same with Linq2DB in C# with `bar b = new bar; db.Insert(b)`.  Thanks!